# How to remove database connection in hibernate configuration in netbeans?

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, oracle10g

I have created an Oracle database connection while creating Hibernate application in NetBeans 8.0. But now I want to remove the connection that is appearing in the drop down list containing label `Database connection`.

How do I remove that connection from the list so that I can create the same connection as a new connection?

The reason to remove the connection is that I wanted to practice creating the connection to the database while using Hibernate framework. When I try to create the same connection that I had created, then I get an error stating *Unable to add connection. Connection already exists.*

Answer (score 1):

First you need to disconnect from your database connection. Then

1. Open Data Source Enterprise Explorer by go to window -> Show View -> Other -> Data Management (in Hibernate perspective) -> Data Source Explorer
2. Expand the category for the connection profile you want to delete.
3. Delete the connection that you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Netbeans' Services window and expand the databases option in the Services menu. You will find your database connection within the items listed. Right click on it and then:

1. disconnect
2. delete